# Android open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system) error

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

Im having an issue extracting the contents of a zip file to a directory on my SD card. When I debug the app, I can see the error listed as `java.io.FileNotFoundException:/ testFile.zip: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system) error`

I have already made sure that I the manifest file includes

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Im a little lost why I am getting this message because the contents that I want to unzip are located on the SD card.

Comment: Please post you post your `FileManagement` class.

Comment: And post the values of selectedFile and droppedItem, make sure they're in a place you can legally write.

Comment: selectedItem is an item that I am dragging from a list. It is set by `item.getText().toString();` where item is `ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);` I have not included the fileManagement class because its very, very long.

Comment: You were asked to tell what the value was of selectedItem. Not how you came to it as we have no idea what the path would become. What is the path in selectedItem? And where are you going to store the unzipped files? Exact path please.

Comment: `error listed as java.io.FileNotFoundException:/ testFile.zip:`. Dont believe you. If you really wanted to save to sdcard then you would see an absolute path there. Not a short file name. And why that leading space?

Answer (score 1):

Log the folder paths and make sure they are pointing to the location that you expect.

Since we don't have all the relevant code it's hard to determine exactly what the problem is, or even if there is a problem in the code at all.

I just got a simple example working and tested, using code from [Here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Unzipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29).
Maybe this will help to see a working example to use as a reference in order to make sure that your code is correct.

I used a simple zip file containing two nested folders and a text file `hello/secondFolder/hello.txt`.

As you can see in the logs, it's using the virtual `sdcard` on my device: `/storage/emulated/0/`.

Decompress.java (taken directly from the link above):

```
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

/**
 *
 * @author jon
 */
public class Decompress {
    private String _zipFile;
    private String _location;

    public Decompress(String zipFile, String location) {
        _zipFile = zipFile;
        _location = location;

        _dirChecker("");
    }

    public void unzip() {
        try  {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile);
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin);
            ZipEntry ze = null;
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                Log.v("Unzip", "Unzipping " + ze.getName());

                if(ze.isDirectory()) {
                    _dirChecker(ze.getName());
                } else {
                    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName());
                    for (int c = zin.read(); c != -1; c = zin.read()) {
                        fout.write(c);
                    }

                    zin.closeEntry();
                    fout.close();
                }

            }
            zin.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("Unzip", "unzip exception", e);
        }

    }

    private void _dirChecker(String dir) {
        File f = new File(_location + dir);

        if(!f.isDirectory()) {
            f.mkdirs();
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String zipFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/helloWithFolder.zip";
        String unzipLocation = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/unzipped/";

        Log.d("Unzip", "Zipfile: " + zipFile);
        Log.d("Unzip", "location: " + unzipLocation);

        Decompress d = new Decompress(zipFile, unzipLocation);
        d.unzip();
    }
```

logs:

```
04-03 12:11:06.472  19427-19427/com.zipfile.daniel.zipfileextract D/Unzip﹕ Zipfile: /storage/emulated/0/helloWithFolder.zip
04-03 12:11:06.472  19427-19427/com.zipfile.daniel.zipfileextract D/Unzip﹕ location: /storage/emulated/0/unzipped/
04-03 12:11:06.472  19427-19427/com.zipfile.daniel.zipfileextract V/Unzip﹕ Unzipping hello/
04-03 12:11:06.472  19427-19427/com.zipfile.daniel.zipfileextract V/Unzip﹕ Unzipping hello/secondFolder/
04-03 12:11:06.472  19427-19427/com.zipfile.daniel.zipfileextract V/Unzip﹕ Unzipping hello/secondFolder/hello.txt
```

Verification that it unzipped successfully:

```
shell@jfltetmo:/sdcard $ cd unzipped
shell@jfltetmo:/sdcard/unzipped $ ls
hello
shell@jfltetmo:/sdcard/unzipped $ cd hello
shell@jfltetmo:/sdcard/unzipped/hello $ ls
secondFolder
shell@jfltetmo:/sdcard/unzipped/hello $ cd secondFolder
shell@jfltetmo:/sdcard/unzipped/hello/secondFolder $ ls
hello.txt
shell@jfltetmo:/sdcard/unzipped/hello/secondFolder $ cat hello.txt
hello
```

Edit:
I just tested with a bad zip name and got this error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/helloBad.zip: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`